# Rails - How can I put the create/new action from one controller into the index of another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new. If this question has been asked before I sincerely apologize, I'm not that good at finding the words to come up with the search.

I have two controllers: games and predictions

Think of games as blog posts. When a new game is generated, I post them all to /games/ (which I made my index page for the whole site)

These games all have options on them with a form submit button at the bottom. Is there a way to make this submit button generate a new prediction from the predictions controller? I guess what I'm asking is can I render the predictions controller's create/new methods on the index of the games controller? Is it as simple as putting in the form_for action with all the fields in the index.html.erb file for the games view?

Thanks in advance. I'm sure I'm not the only one who's asked this so I will search through SO more extensively.

Comment: Do you want to route to a new page or render it on the current page?

Comment: when I submit? I think I'd like to render it on the current page.

 Oh snap can I just put <%= form_for @prediction do |f| %> in the right place on the game/index view? There's probably going to be some routing issue. I'm going to try this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to submit a request with the form information to the Predictions Controller. Then, you want the Predictions Controller to return some html that you can then render on the page without a refresh.

To do this, you should read up on making AJAX requests with Rails. I did a quick Google and found this article that seems to be a pretty quick explanation of it. There will probably be some gaps in their description but I think it can get you most of the way there:

https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

The general idea is your page is going to make a request to the server, just like a normal page request, except the browser is NOT going to reload the page with the request's response. Instead, you're going to write some javascript to instruct the browser on what to do with the response once its received.

Comment: I went through that guide and then branched off for a couple hours on similar ideas. I think before I even care about dynamically changing information on one page, I want to get the form to just redirect. For example, when the form on "/games" submits, I'd like it to submit a new prediction object and then go to "/predictions" where I have the show method that shows all predictions. I'm just confused because in the <%= form_for ... portion of the form, obviously a variable @prediction isn't declared in the game controller. How do I go about declaring that variable in the game controller?

Comment: I'm super rusty with Rails but I think, based on your description, a Game has a relationship with one (or many) Prediction(s). What I think you want is to collect all the data needed to create a new prediction. Do you have a form for each @game on the page? If so, you *might* be able to render each form using <% form_for([@game, @prediction]) %> . This is assuming the Game model has a association set up with Predictions ("has_many :predictions" in the Game model). This is the closest scenario I could track down: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702459/ruby-on-rails-association-form

Comment: that's exactly the association I was looking for. My mind just cleared up, thanks!